# How to delete a line from a file with sed following a pattern

Tags: sed

I have a file with the following lines:

```
auth_service_oauth_secret_accfrsh
auth_service_oauth_secret_accfrshv12
auth_service_oauth_secret_accfrshv13
```

I would like to be able to remove only the first line, where my pattern will be only "**accfrsh**", but I tried with multiple sed commands and it's not working. All lines with the pattern "**accfrsh**" are removed or nothing change.

I tried the below sed commands (it doesn't matter with -e or -i) :

```
sed -e "/accfrsh/d" my_file (remove all lines)
sed -e 's/\<accfrsh\>//g' my_file (nothing changes)
sed -e "/'^'accfrsh'$'/d" my_file (nothing changes)
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/_accfrsh\b/d' file
```

Delete lines which contain `_accfrsh` followed by a word boundary.

Compare it to:

```
sed '/_accfrsh\B/d' file
```

N.B. The `\b` is related to  `/<` and `/>` which denote the start and end of a word boundary (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to remove the first line matches

```
sed -i '0,/accfrsh/{//d}' my_file
```

The command will start at the beginning of the file (line 0) and ends at the first occurrence of the pattern "accfrsh."
{//d} will delete the line